# Using jenkins want to run cucumber test cases but it fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, jenkins

Using jenkins want to run cucumber test cases using the following command, but it fails and throws below error.

```
$ bash -c "source /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/scripts/rvm && cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/primefactors/workspace/ && rvm use ruby 1.8.7 && bundle --quiet && bundle exec cucumber -p  -c no_proxy=127.0.0.1 browser=chrome  --no-color"
```

The error is:

```
bash: /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory ERROR:  (Java::Hudson::AbortException)
```

Comment: Are you sure file `/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/scripts/rvm` really exists on a system where you execute your tests?